# (SpringBoot) In this case how to pass the parameters from controller layer to service layer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The json that I have to send looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "height": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "list": [
    {
      "klk": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "subject": 0,
      "subjectType": "string",
      "target": 0
    }
  ],
  "type": "string",
  "group": 0,
  "width": 0
}
```

```
class First {
   private Long id;
   private Integer height;
   private Integer width;
   private String name;
   private String type;
   private Long group;
   private List<Second> list;
}

class Second {
   private Long klk;
   private String name;
   private String subjectType;
   private Long subject;
   private Long target;
}
```

So basically I have a DTO that contains a list of DTOs. As you can see both DTOs have a lot of parameters.

How to pass the values to the service layer without passing 10 parameters (or the DTO itself)?

I need some ideas...

Comment: Whats wrong with passing the DTO, that contains all the information you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use getter and setter or use Jackson Annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as List where Object can be any class type from the 10 class .
And at service layer side use below implementation to identify type of class .

```
    pseudo code
    for()
    {
    if(list.get(i).getClass().equals(First.class))
      {
       logic for class first
    }
else if(..)
   //same way you can do it using if else or switch
```

}